# I cannot retrieve the output from this vector

Tags: c++, vector, output

I'm only new to C++ and I've been working on this short program. I can't seem to find what is wrong with it. It outputs the first_name string fine but when I try to output the contents of the vector I've called w, nothing happens. I'd appreciate any help. No doubt there is a simple explanation such as some syntax I've missed. Thanks!

```
    int main()
{
    cout<< "Please enter the first name of the person you are writing to\n";
    string  first_name = "??";
    cin >>  first_name;
    vector<string>w;
    cout << "Enter your message to "<<first_name<<"?\n";
    for(string word; cin>>word;)
    w.push_back(word);
    for(int i=0; i<w.size();++i)
        cout<<w[i]<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That first `for` loop is completely, irredeemably wrong. You must remove it and do two things (in no particular order): 1) consider what you want the code to do, and how it is to know when to stop, and 2) study the syntax of `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't stop you for loop

```
    int main()
{
    cout<< "Please enter the first name of the person you are writing to\n";
    string  first_name = "??";
    cin >>  first_name;
    vector<string>w;
    cout << "Enter your message to "<<first_name<<"?\n";
    for(string word; cin>>word && word != "q";)
        w.push_back(word);
    for(int i=0; i<w.size();++i)
        cout<<w[i]<<'\n';
}
```

That worked for me. It will be just an infinite loop but if you pass to it q it will stop

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I would have forgotten something simple like that

Comment: I've just run this and it still doesn't seem to be working. Could it be something I'm missing from the standard library?

Comment: Can you describe what you get as the output?